# Map.of for Java in Scala

Tags: java, scala

How to call static **varg** overloads of java Map from Scala?

for ex :

```scala
 val map: java.util.Map[Char,Int] =
  java.util.Map.of('Z', 5, 'R', 2, 'X', 9, 'A', 4, 'F', 1)
```

This fails with **Error** as Scala treats of as member of Map.

```scala
    Value of is not a member of object java.util.Map
          java.util.Map.of('Z', 5, 'R', 2, 'X', 9, 'A', 4, 'F', 1)
                        ^Compilation Failed
```

Comment: Which JDK are you using? Map.of appears only JDK 9+

Comment: @IvanKurchenko hey my bad it was 1.8. Some how my default got changed in my env. Let me check with latest java and updare all

Comment: Is using Map.of a requirement ? If you are not aware, there are converters from scala to Java
With `  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`
and `val map: util.Map[Char, Int] = Map('Z' ->5, 'R' -> 2, 'X'-> 9, 'A'-> 4, 'F'-> 1).asJava`

Comment: This worked fine with JVM version update.

Answer (score 4):

Note that [`Map.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-) was introduced with **Java SE 9** and therefore your code will fail to compile with pre-Java9 JDK.

Another important fact you should keep in mind is that using `Map.of`, you can store **a maximum of 10 entries** only, and for each number of entries (zero to 10), there is a separate `Map.of` defined. So, it's **NOT** a varg.

e.g. the following statement is correct

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = Map.of('A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3, 'D', 4, 'E', 5, 'F', 6, 'G', 7, 'H', 8, 'I', 9,
                'J',  10);
```

but **NOT** the following one:

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = Map.of('A', 1, 'B', 2, 'C', 3, 'D', 4, 'E', 5, 'F', 6, 'G', 7, 'H', 8, 'I', 9,
                'J', 10,'K',11);
```

If you want to store more than 10 entries using a single statement like this, you can use [`Map#ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-).

**Demo:**

```
import static java.util.Map.entry;

import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = Map.ofEntries(entry('A', 1), entry('B', 2), entry('C', 3), entry('D', 4),
                entry('E', 5), entry('F', 6), entry('G', 7), entry('H', 8), entry('I', 9), entry('J', 10),
                entry('K', 11));

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{K=11, J=10, I=9, H=8, G=7, F=6, E=5, D=4, C=3, B=2, A=1}
```